# Adding more than one item to Woocommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am currently using `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` which creates an add to cart button. I have an input box with + and - to select a custom amount of products. Is there anyway of taking an amount from an input box and padding it into this function to add a custom amount of products at once?

The cart code hooked in is as follows:

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

This is directly from the Woocommerce plugin

Comment: Please include code for the "Add to Cart" button, so we can see what have you done and how can we extend that to help you add quantity to cart.

Comment: Thank you I have added the code above. I really want to know if I can pass a parameter to woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item or similar to add more than one item to the cart

Comment: I almost have the solution for you but just want to know the output of $product->add_to_cart_url(). Just share a sample url of any product

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice **"This is directly from the Woocommerce plugin"**. This means you don't have control over the code above, I mean you shouldn't edit that. Alternatively, I can help you acomplish this with JS if you could include HTML output of any product, I need to see the Quantity Up/Down and this **Add To Cart** anchor tag in action

Comment: Sure. It currently adds via AJAX and the URL is:

`code`<a rel="nofollow" href="/helenshillwp/shop/?removed_item=1&amp;add-to-cart=1887" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="1887" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>`code`

Comment: You need to send the quantity as an attribute named `quantity` so in the URL above, it must be `/helenshillwp/shop/?removed_item=1&amp;add-to-cart=188‌​7&quantity=5`. Since I don't have access to the AJAX code or your working environment, I can't propose exact solution

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just assuming Woocommerce had a built in feature to add multiple items at once. But I guess maybe not. The only issue might be that the cart is already being updated by AJAX, just so you know beforehand. Below is my current html

Comment: Thanks - nearly there. What about passing quantity directly to the 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' function?

Comment: That's also possible, [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart.html#671-694). `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( array('quanitity' => 5) )`